# Is it O'K to add class properties and constructor to Laravel Controller class?

Tags: php, laravel

I want to perform my PHP/Laravel code, so to make it easier in support I tried to add class properties to `Controller`. Everything works, but I want to know is it acceptable trick from the view point of Laravel framework.

```
class TopPageController extends Controller {

    private $request;
    private $pageHtmlHeadData;

    public function __construct() {
        $this -> pageHtmlHeadData =  $this -> getTopPageHtmlHeadData();
    }


    public function renderTopPage(Request $request){
        $this -> request = $request;
        dd('Enougn for now');
    }

    private function getTopPageHtmlHeadData(){
       retrun // SQL request ...
    }
}
```

As you see, in the code above I did two unusual things: setup the `$this -> request` instance when  `renderTopPage()` was called from the `web.php` (now we can access to if from any method of the class) and perform sql request when the instance of `TopPageController` has been created (really I don't know when it was).

Comment: What do you mean by SQL request?

Comment: Yes, you may add either as your needs see fit. It's common practice to do so if you are subclassing your controllers, for instance, in the case of different api versions.

Comment: @Camilo, In this case I get some data like `<title>`, `<meta description>` etc. from the database for the View.

Comment: The request object is a special case. You don't need to assign it to a property because it is accessible via `request()` or the `Request` facade.

Comment: @btl, calling via facade is deprecated, is not it? So `request()` helper will be the better alternative, I suppose.

Comment: @btl, Thank you for the help! My code becomes cleaner.

Comment: @Gurebu Bokofu Where did you see the request facade was deprecated? It doesn't appear to be in the api docs. https://laravel.com/api/5.5/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Request.html

Comment: @btl, if try to call, for example, `Request::all()`, it will be `Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically` exception. It has `(E_DEPRECATED)` type.

Comment: I don't know I have never seen that before. Typically deprecations  are well documented as they can lead to breaking changes. Nothing in the Laravel docs indicates that being the case.

Comment: @btl, do you use old version of laravel?

Comment: "now we can access to if from any method of the class" Wrong. Only if it is set in constructor which is by it's nature called on every request before method's execution.

Comment: No, I use v5.5.

Comment: I think this question belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/